# Export .csv from database with symfony2

Tags: symfony, csv, export-to-csv

I didn't get this method to work, maybe someone has an idea.

```
/**
 * @Route("/export", name="export")
 * @Template("AppBundle:Expenses:export.html.twig")
 */
public function exportAction()
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Expenses');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $query->orderBy('s.id', 'DESC');

    $data = $query->getQuery()->getResult(); $filename = "export_".date("Y_m_d_His").".csv";

    $response = $this->render('AppBundle:Expenses:export.html.twig', array('data' => $data));

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Description', 'Submissions Export');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires', '0');

    return $response;
}
```

I got:

```
Unable to find Expenses entity.
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
```

The funny thing:
In an other method this is working:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Expenses')->find($id);
```

So, there is really an Expenses Entity under AppBundle. Where is the error come from?

--
My routes:

```
[router] Current routes
 Name                     Method Scheme Host Path
 _assetic_bootstrap_css   ANY    ANY    ANY  /styles/bootstrap.css
 _assetic_bootstrap_css_0 ANY    ANY    ANY  /styles/bootstrap__bootstrap_1.css
 _assetic_bootstrap_css_1 ANY    ANY    ANY  /styles/bootstrap_form_2.css
 _assetic_bootstrap_js    ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_0  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_transition_1.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_1  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_alert_2.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_2  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_button_3.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_3  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_carousel_4.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_4  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_collapse_5.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_5  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_dropdown_6.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_6  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_modal_7.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_7  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_tooltip_8.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_8  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_popover_9.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_9  ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_scrollspy_10.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_10 ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_tab_11.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_11 ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_affix_12.js
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_12 ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/bootstrap_bc-bootstrap-collection_13.js
 _assetic_jquery          ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/jquery.js
 _assetic_jquery_0        ANY    ANY    ANY  /javascripts/jquery_jquery-1.11.1_1.js
 _assetic_fddb9b6         ANY    ANY    ANY  /css/fddb9b6.css
 _assetic_fddb9b6_0       ANY    ANY    ANY  /css/fddb9b6_part_1.css
 _assetic_ae00be7         ANY    ANY    ANY  /styles/all.css
 _assetic_ae00be7_0       ANY    ANY    ANY  /styles/all_part_1_main_1.css
 _assetic_215113c         ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/215113c.js
 _assetic_215113c_0       ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/215113c_part_1.js
 _assetic_cd44034         ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/cd44034.js
 _assetic_cd44034_0       ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/cd44034_part_1.js
 _wdt                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
 _profiler_home           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
 _profiler_search         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search
 _profiler_search_bar     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar
 _profiler_purge          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge
 _profiler_info           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}
 _profiler_phpinfo        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo
 _profiler_search_results ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results
 _profiler                ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}
 _profiler_router         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router
 _profiler_exception      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception
 _profiler_exception_css  ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 _configurator_home       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
 _configurator_step       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}
 _configurator_final      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final
 _twig_error_test         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_error/{code}.{_format}
 dashboard                ANY    ANY    ANY  /
 seite2                   ANY    ANY    ANY  /seite2
 seite3                   ANY    ANY    ANY  /seite3
 expenses                 GET    ANY    ANY  /expenses/
 expenses_create          POST   ANY    ANY  /expenses/
 expenses_new             GET    ANY    ANY  /expenses/new
 expenses_show            GET    ANY    ANY  /expenses/{id}
 expenses_edit            GET    ANY    ANY  /expenses/{id}/edit
 expenses_update          PUT    ANY    ANY  /expenses/{id}
 expenses_delete          DELETE ANY    ANY  /expenses/{id}
 expenses_export          GET    ANY    ANY  /expenses/export
 userLogin                ANY    ANY    ANY  /login
 userLoginCheck           ANY    ANY    ANY  /login_check
 userLogout               ANY    ANY    ANY  /logout
 userRegister             ANY    ANY    ANY  /register
 user                     GET    ANY    ANY  /user/
 user_new                 ANY    ANY    ANY  /user/new
 user_show                GET    ANY    ANY  /user/{id}
 user_edit                GET    ANY    ANY  /user/{id}/edit
 user_update              PUT    ANY    ANY  /user/{id}
 user_delete              DELETE ANY    ANY  /user/{id}
 login                    ANY    ANY    ANY  /login
 login_check              ANY    ANY    ANY  /login_check
```

Comment: I think you've a rooting problem try execute `php app\console router:debug`

Comment: thank you for your help! I got `expenses_export          ANY    ANY    ANY  /expenses/export` - How can I fix the routing problem? Any idea? :-)

Comment: Show us your routes (in your question, not in comments), it might help ;)

Comment: updated in the quesion. :-)

Comment: strange error i suppose you've check your url in your bowser. If yes two action can help : `cache:clear` in first and try again. second just put a `die` in your broken method to check she's called (or not)